# Taking out block of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a big numpy matrix (4*4):

```
A = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h],[i,j,k,l],[m,n,o,p]]
```

From that matrix i would love to extract a 3*3 matrix if i give it a position. For example:

```
p = (0,0)
```

is the element a. Then the block i am looking for is this:

```
[[a,b,c],[e,f,g],[i,j,k]]
```

if I gave the position p(3,3), it's element k in the 4*4 matrix. I am looking for the block:

```
[[f,g,h],[j,k,l],[n,o,p]]
```

This is a bit confusing, so i made this drawing:

[image]

Black is the 4*4 matrix, red is the matrix from p(0,0) and green is the matrix from p(3,3)

Comment: Is the logic for p(0,0) and p(3,3) the same?

Comment: How do you know which 3x3 matrix to choose?

Comment: It's always a 3*3 matrix i need. The size is fixed. The p is just a position vector for the element

Comment: There is only one submatrix containing element `a`, but there are four different submatrices containing element `k`. You need to specify the exact logic for the operation you are trying to implement, as the question currently stands there are several possible functions that would give you that result for the examples that you give in spite of having quite different behaviors in general.